# Json.Net Deserializing "NA" for Numeric Values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, numeric

I am trying to deserialize numeric data using Json.Net where a value might be specified as "NA" if it is missing, e.g.

```
{
    "readings": [
        { "temperature" : 75 } ,
        { "temperature" : "NA" }
    ]
}
```

I would like to parse the values into a *double?* type, e.g.

```
public class Reading
{
    public double? Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

Where (net effect) the first Reading from my example would be "75" and the second would be "null".

I do not have any control over the JSON that is being provided to me.

Is a JsonConverter the only way to get Json.Net to handle this for me, or is there some easier way?  (I can always create a private class variable for the Json deserialized value and then add my own public property that does whatever I want to the private value, but as I have a lot of properties to deal with it would be a lot of extra code.)

Comment: You can use NewtonSoft's Json library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest building a custom type converter, but if you *really* don't want to, you can [implement an error handler](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationerrorhandling.htm) that disregards deserialization exceptions. Assuming you have a setup like this:

```
public class Reading
{
    public double? Temperature { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Reading> Readings { get; set; }
}
```

You can write something like this:

```
Root obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(
    json, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = (sender, args) =>
        {
            Reading reading = args.CurrentObject as Reading;

            if (reading != null && args.ErrorContext.Member.ToString() == "temperature")
            {
                reading.Temperature = null;
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here we're handling the `Error` event and marking the error handled if we've detected an error while deserializing the `temperature` member.

Just in case you'd like to use a custom converter, here's what it could look like:

```
public class NAConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Reading);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        Reading reading = new Reading();
        string tempStr = obj.Value<string>("temperature");

        double temp;

        if (Double.TryParse(tempStr, out temp))
        {
            reading.Temperature = temp;
        }

        return reading;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I came across this in the Json.Net documentation.  It appears that one can specify a converter on a per-property basis:<br><br>

    // new Date(976918263055)
    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

Comment: (Aargh.  Apologies for the bad formatting -- didn't read the help closely enough.)

Comment: @BoCoKeith: Yep! That's definitely an option as well. Whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, make temperature a string in your model and then use `TryParse` to see if it can be converted to a double or not.

```
double tempValue;

if (Double.TryParse(yourObject.Temperature, out temp)){
  // successfully parsed to a double
  // do whatever you're going to do with the value
}
else {
  // couldn't be parsed as a double, handle accordingly
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is way to have the deserializer convert the string to a nullable double. Best to deserialize the value as a string, then handle converting the string to an numeric value when you are using it.

so you could try something like this:

```
 public class Reading
{
public string Temperature {get; set;}
private double? _NumTemperature;
public Double? NumTemperature{
get{ return _NumTemperature} 
set{
Double n;
bool isNumeric = double.TryParse(Temperature, out n);
if (isNumeric)
{
_NumTemperature = n;
}
else
{
_NumTemperature = null;
}
}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET allows you to [create JsonConverter subclasses](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to handle special cases; you override a few methods and pass it to the `JsonConvert.Deserialise*` methods

So your steps are to create a class roughly like so;

```
public NAConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) { return t == typeof(string); }
    public override ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in ReadJson, you'll be able to ask the JsonReader if it's pointing at a string, and if that's "NA". If so, return null or zero or Double.IsNaN; otherwise, defer to the base.

Then pass an instance to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` or `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>()`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your class as following and use [Newtonsoft Json library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialization/deserialization:

```
public class Reading
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double? Temperature { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperature")]
    private string TemperatureString 
    {
        get
        {
            return Temperature.HasValue ? Temperature.Value.ToString() :"NA";
        }
        set
        {
            double result;
            Temperature = double.TryParse(value, out result) ? result : null;
        }
    }
}
```